# Dask task to worker appointment

Tags: python, dask

[image: Current task to worker appointment]

I run a computation graph with long functions (several hours) and big results (several hundred of megabytes). This type of load can be atypical for dask.
I try to run this graph on 4 workers. I see  depicted task to worker appointment:

In first row "green" task depends only on a "blue" one, not "violet". Why green task is not moved  to other worker?
Is it possible to give some hints to a scheduler to always move a task on a free worker? Which information do you need and possible to obtain which helps to debug more?

Such appointment is non-optimal and graph computation takes more time than necessary.

A little bit information:

- Computation graph composing is done using `dask.delayed`
- Computation invocation is done using next code

```
    to_compute = [result_of_dask_delayed_1, ... , result_of_dask_delayed_n]
    running = client.persist(to_compute)
    results = as_completed(
            futures_of(running),
            with_results=True,
            raise_errors=not bool(cmdline_options.partial_fails),
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, we should state stat scheduling tasks to workers is complicated - please read [this description](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/scheduling-policies.html). Roughly, when a batch of tasks come in, they will be distributed to workers, accounting for dependencies.

Dask has no idea, before running, how long any given task will take or how big the data result it generates might be. Once a task is done, this information is available for the completed task (but not for ones still waiting to run), but dask needs to make a decision on whether to [steal](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/work-stealing.html) an allotted task to an idle worker, and copy across the data it needs to run. Please read the link to see how this is done.

Finally, you can indeed have more fine-grained control over where things are run, e.g., [this section](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/locality.html#specify-workers-with-compute-persist).

Comment: Does calling same function with different arguments counts as new task?

Comment: A task is the combination of function and arguments, but dask may use previous similar tasks to guess the duration of a task yet to run

Comment: In my graph several independent direction with similar stages for each one. Next pattern is used for naming `dask_key_name=<direction>::<stage_name>::<timestamp>`. All sub strings doesn't contain `-`. What is common prefix In this case?